# simulate x where $\sum x = 0, \sum x^2 = a, \sum x^3 = b$

Tags: simulation, skewness

I would like to simulate a random variable $x$ with the following properties
($x_i$ being one simulation)

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = a$
3. $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 = b$

If I am correct:

- from 1 it directly follows that the **mean** must be zero
- from 2 it follows that **variance** must be $\frac{a}{n}$

**What follows from 3.?**

I guess it is something related to the skewness...

Comment: Note that if you sample $n$ points from a distribution with mean zero, it doesn't guarantee that your $n$ points will have $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$.

Comment: So, just to be explicit about @Dougal's question: do you want the *simulated data* to have these properties or do you want the *underlying random variable* to have them?  Or both?  And why?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The equalities do not have to be perfectly matched. Matching them in expectation is enough.

Comment: Simulated data should have these properties, but just on average is enough. I do not need a perfect match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn't mention any other constraints on the distribution, then grab any distribution with three parameters, such as [normal skew distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution). You can pick the parameters to match those three through moments.

Comment: Thank you. What is the third moment I am aiming for?

Comment: You can target skewness or straight 3rd noncentral moment

Comment: But I don't think my third constraint is equal to the skewness. Or am I wrong? How do I go from my third constraint to a specific skewness in terms of a and b and n?

Comment: @PalimPalim It's easier to think about in terms of the plain third moment $\mathbb E[X^3]$; you want $\mathbb E[X^3] = \frac{b}{n}$. $\gamma_1$ given in the linked wiki article is $\mathbb E\left[ \frac{(X - \mu)^3}{\sigma^3} \right]$, from which since your $\mu = 0$ it's easy to see that $\gamma_1 = \frac{b/n}{(a/n)^{3/2}} = \frac{b \sqrt{n}}{a^3}$.