# simulate r.v.s $a$ & $b$ with $\mathbf{E}[ a^2b] = c$

Tags: simulation, covariance, skewness

I would like to simulate two random variables $a$ and $b$ they should have the following property

$\mathbf{E}[a^2b] = c $

where $c$ can be any number, positive or negative.

Additional constraints

- $\mathbf{E}[a] = 0$
- $\mathbf{E}[b] = 0$
- $\mathbf{E}[a^2] = 1$

**<s>What kind of relationship is my expectation?</s> How could I achieve that? <s>Do I need a specific Co-skewness Co-variance?</s>**

---

Thinking about it I recognized that $\mathbf{E}[a^2b] = Cov(a^2,b) - \mathbf{E}[a^2] \mathbf{E}[b]= Cov(a^2,b)$

Also, this means that the Co-Skewness $ \kappa(a,a,b) = c$ if Co-Skewness is defined as follows $\kappa(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \frac{\mathbf{E} \left[ (x_1 - \mathbf{E}(x_1)) (x_2 - \mathbf{E}(x_2)) (x_3 - \mathbf{E}(x_3))\right]}{\mathbf{V}(x_1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathbf{V}(x_2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \mathbf{V}(x_3)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

---

**Further Background Information:**

I am working with an algorithm presented in this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Spiridon_Penev2/publication/317032461_Random_Orthogonal_Matrix_Simulation_with_Exact_Means_Covariances_and_Multivariate_Skewness/links/594a4dc7aca2723195de4a72/Random-Orthogonal-Matrix-Simulation-with-Exact-Means-Covariances-and-Multivariate-Skewness.pdf). The algorithm can be used in a simulation which matches mean, covariance and a measure of multivariate skewness aka kollo skewness. For this algorithm, you need an L matrix. The problem above is part of the search for such an L matrix. The first column of the L matrix must fulfill the following properties, where $\alpha_i$ is the ith element of the first column of the $L$ matrix

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 0$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 = n$
3. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^3 = nb_1$

The other columns must fulfill, where $\beta$ represents a column which is not the first and $\beta_i$ one element of that column.

1. $\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i = 0$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i^2 = n$
3. $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i^2 \beta_i = nb_k$ where k referes to the column $\beta$ represents

This is always fullfilled thorugh an optimization. But I would like to make this optimization easier by already roughly fulfilling these requirements. This question should help me find a sample which already roughly fulfills the second set of requirements.

Comment: Maybe you can simulate $h, b$ as a bivariate normal, where $h = a^2$.
Set $Cov(h, b) = c$, $E[h] = 1$, $E[b] = 0$. Not sure if you can get $E[\sqrt{h}] = 0$ though.

Comment: sounds interesting but h must be always positive than and this is not the case for a bivariate normal.

Comment: and also, I already have a and would like to only tweak b :-P

Comment: This needs the same kind of clarifications requested of your previous question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300580/simulate-x-where-sum-x-0-sum-x2-a-sum-x3-b.  Furthermore, these kinds of questions have little (if any) interest statistically; they're too broad and don't have definite answers. Could you explain *why* you want to simulate variables with these properties?  Then you would have a chance of getting answers that aren't perfectly arbitrary.

Comment: @whuber please check my edits and consider removing put on hold